# undefined method 'map' for :id:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol):
    # duels/_user_challenges.html.erb
    1: <div id="dropdown-no-2">
    2:    <%= collection_select 'challenge_id', challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true %>.
    3: </div>
```

When a user selects a user to `duel` then only the challenges for that respective user should be shown.

**duels/_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:name),:id, :full_name, include_blank: true, id: "id_of_the_user_id_select_box" %>
  will

<%= render :partial => 'user_challenges', locals: {challenges: Challenge.order(:deadline)} %>

<script>
  $( "#id_of_the_user_id_select_box" ).change(function() {
       $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '<%= user_challenges_path %>',
          data: {name: $('#id_of_the_user_id_select_box').prop('value')}
       });
  });
</script>
```

**duels/user_challenges.js.erb**

```
$("#dropdown-no-2").html('<%=j render :partial => "user_challenges", locals: {challenges: @challenges} %>');
```

**duels_controller.rb**

```
def user_challenges
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @challenges = @user.challenges.order(:deadline)
end
```

Comment: The second parameter of `collection_select` should be a `method`. And the collection should be passed as the third parameter. Check http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: Shouldn't you specify an object in collection_select to which the 'select' tag will be applied? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: Like this, `<%= collection_select(:challenge, :challenge_id, challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true) %>.`? That got rid of the error, but `dropdown-no-2` is still listing all the challenges instead of only the challenges for that respective user. @MishaSlyusarev

Comment: you are passing `name` parameter in the controller method. But you're searching with id parameter. `User.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: You might be right, but doesn't work either way @Emu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select.

I suggest using the `select` FormHelper to achieve this:

So this

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:name),:id, :full_name, include_blank: true, id: "id_of_the_user_id_select_box" %>
```

Becomes this

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] }, include_blank: true, id: "id_of_the_user_id_select_box" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion :) Problem persists though with all the challenges still be listed.